# Ionic 3 Post to REST API (Swagger)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I want to send a text to a REST API (Swagger). This endpoint accepts text and returns a JSON.

**Error**

*Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.RestProvider.post')*

**My REST Provider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {
private apiUrl = 'https://xxxxx.com/xxxx/?language=DE'; 
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

}
```

**Request in home.ts**

```
getDiagnosis(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.RestProvider.post(this.apiUrl, data,{headers:{'Content-Type': 'text'}})
      .subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
     }); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call `this.RestProvider.post` which doesn't contain in your RestProvider.

Define a `getDiagnosis(data)` method in your `RestProvider` Class and call it from your `home.ts` class.

RestProvider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Set Headers to post request
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 'Content-Type': 'text' },
  )
};

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {
private apiUrl = 'https://xxxxx.com/xxxx/?language=DE'; 
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

getDiagnosis(data): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data, httpOptions);
    }
}
```

home.ts

```
export class Home {
    constructor(private restProvider : RestProvider) {

    }

    getDiagnosis(data) {
        this.restProvider.getDiagnosis(data)
            .subscribe(response => {
                //Do whatever you want with response data
            });
    }
}
```